# php://output doesn't export files (but entering a file name works)

Tags: php, excel

```
    $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($sheetInfo);
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blah.xls"');
    ob_end_clean();
    $writer->save('php://output');
```

I saw other posts related to how to download excel files which are generated with *PHPExcel*.
In my case, if the final line is a valid file name `(E.g.$writer->save('blah.xls'))`, the file is generated inside the project file.

Still, `$writer->save('php://output')` doesn't produce anything.

I also put the following lines before `new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5`, but still I was no luck.

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
```

Is there anything else to do, in order to download the file?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Was my answer helpful? Please upvote if so, and mark accepted if it answered your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this library, but you could just save to a file and then output it:

```
if ($tempfile = tempnam("/tmp", "xls")) {
    $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($sheetInfo);
    $writer->save($tempfile);
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blah.xls"');
    echo file_get_contents($tempfile);
    unlink($tempfile);
} else {
    echo "Unable to save temp file!";
    die;
}
```